# Need further explanation on ESP8266 SDWebServer example code

Tags: webserver, sd-card, esp8266

I'm trying to understand the ESP web server from SD card, by the [example code](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/SDWebServer/SDWebServer.ino). And I simply don't see how the server respond to "/" request, since in other server examples usually there is a  `server.on("/", WhateverFunction);` line, but not on this example.

Whats calling the `loadFromSdCard` function? What would be the simplest way to open a file from SD card? Or a simply line by line explanation on whats happening on would be appreciated too

Comment: `void handleNotFound(){ if(hasSD && loadFromSdCard(server.uri())) return;`. That's it, it just loads the requested URI from the SD card and returns it.

Comment: why does the not found handles the loading. That's a confusing way  to put it. Also, is there a way to separate that? I want to run my own code before the `loadFromSdCard` fetch the files.

Comment: Look at line 252 following. (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples/SDWebServer/SDWebServer.ino#L252). The examples handles code only the paths `/list`, `/edit` (with GET, PUT, DELETE, POST) with the functions `printDirectory`, `handleDelete` and `handleCreate`. If the request path is not equal to either `/list` or `/edit` it will trigger the `server.onNotFound(handleNotFound)` handler. This handler then tries to serve the files from the SD card if present, or returns an error otherwise.

Comment: it uses the notfound if you have not hard-coded a requested path using the `server.on` in advance; the url path is literally not found among the definitions. This is a standard part of the http server library, regardless of the SD stuff. To avoid having to hard-code each file name as a url path given to `server.on`, the SD lib defines a handler that first checks to see if any file names happen to match the unreserved path. if one does, it's served instead of 404 error page.